# Sheets API v4 - JS Client: How to add/append a new row to an existing Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Sheets API v4[1] to manipulate a Spreedsheet using Java Script Client API[2].

How can I add a new row without using the `range` property of the `spreadsheets.values.update` method [3]. Is this the only way to add rows using Google Java Script client API?

I just want to add a new row to the end (after last non-empty) of an existing sheet.

Using the `rowCount` or `endRowIndex` properties from the `sheet` object [4] is not an option because I want to add after the last non empty row.

[1] https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/

[2] https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/js

[3] https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update

[4] https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#sheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append new row after your last row by using the AppendCellsRequest of the Spreadsheet collection:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appendcellsrequest

Comment: Hey @user4426017, worked fine here! That's exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks o/